# Testing Gmail Contextual Gadet

Tags: gmail, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Are there any good ways to test a GMail contextual gadget? So far, I have embedded it inside of a Google Site (pointing to the same URL that my Gadget in the console points to)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to connect it with localhost and test. here it is,
you can connect your gadget with localhost and test.
you can use local tunneling for that.
check [ngrok.com](http://ngrok.com)

for me its fine .

for windows , run 'ngrok portnumber'
eg: ngrok 8080  - no need of codes , it gives a link . which you can use instead of your localhost.

Comment: How does this help place a contextual gadget inside of a gmail inbox?